# Facebook iOS share dialog crash

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdk

I have a problem. While sharing on iOS with `FBSDKShareDialog` I encounter a crash when presing (x). Doing this throws only `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` and nothing more. No delegate called or error just crash. Production app connected to the same fb app works properly. I will be gratefull for any advice where to look for.
My share dialog code:

```
let method = user.id == CurrentUser.sharedUser.id ? "some_action" : "other_action"
fbAction.actionType = method
fbAction.setString("\(manager.appHost)\(obj.fbShareUrl)", forKey: "employee")
let content = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent()
content.action = fbAction
content.previewPropertyName = "employee"
FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: showingController, with: content, delegate: showingController)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this. `FBSDKShareDialog` has a property `mode`. I set it to `.web` so the sharing dialog opens now in `UIView` (like a popup) not Safari. In UIView closing buttons works without problem.